# Google Maps v3 performance issues

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm experiencing massive performance issues with the google maps v3 api and could not find anyone with similar issues when searching for this problem. This problem can be seen on any browser, but I'm focussing on Chrome here.

---

### The Symptoms:

When I zoom into the map or out of the map, the FPS rate drops drastically leading to an increadibly bad experience.

---

### My Code:

I implemented the google map using their documentation with the most simple example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

### What I tested so far:

First of all, going to https://maps.google.com and trying out the zoom feature (with the mouse wheel) yields really good results. Everything is smooth and the FPS rate is at 60 fps.
During my tests, I opened both the official google maps website and my small example page, and did the following:

In the Chrome development console I enabled "Show FPS meter". Here are two screenshots taken during a 20-second zoom-in-and-zoom-out session for both the original website and my website.

[image: FPS on my website]
[image: FPS on original website]

Note that the original google maps website does not seem to be using the GPU Memory at all, while my website makes extreme use of it. Actually in the moment of taking the screenshot it was at 146 MB, however, this was fluctuating between 0-200MB with very high speed.

The next thing I did was to enable the **Paint Flashing** feature of the development console in Chrome, which shows the rectangles that are redrawn. I again zoomed in and out of the map and made screenshots:
[image: Paint Flashing on my website]
[image: Paint Flashing on original website]

Here it becomes very clear that my website is trying to repaint only what is changing whilst the original google maps website **always** repaints the whole picture. No matter how long I keep zooming, the original website always repaints the whole thing and does not make any use of the GPU memory at all.

---

### Now my Question:

Has anyone every experienced similar behavior and is there any way (maybe some settings) that let me also render the map just the way google is doing it on their website? My specific use case really makes it impossible to use google maps with the performance I am experiencing.

Comment: I have a similar behavior. Zooming out works fine, but zooming back in results in little freezes. Even if nothing (markers, PolyLine...) is on the map, I can reproduce this behavior.

Comment: Is it this issue: [Issue 9459: Bug: zooming out in Chrome 49 on Android freezes browser tab](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9459)?

Comment: nope, I'm using a PC with the Chrome Version 49.0.2623.87 m - but this problem is reproducable even on other browsers like IE and Firefox.

Comment: Have you looked at my answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason for that is that google maps api it's not the same javascript as google maps application is using.

If you take a look at the resulting map you can see that your map created with the api, is created by multiple divs, each div is one map tile image. 
During zooming every single tile has to be re-rendered with a new image.
Also in the network tab you can see that you are downloading map tiles as images.

On the other hand, google maps application has one canvas element, and during zooming you are not downloading images but vector data (in some google format kind) and they are rendered into the canvas. Canvas object is natively supported and is less expensive than replacing images using DOM elements.

Comment: I would change reference from google maps application to google maps website. Application is confusing term here. Appart from that xxxmatko is right. Google Maps API v3 is using tiles/images and Google Maps website is using some kind of private api with vector data. We should ask google to gives us the access to that private API. Because current v3 is has performance rendering issue (as the question is proof of).

Comment: Thank you for this answer, although I have hoped that there was some way to overcome this performance issue. Unfortunately this makes the api useless to me :/